# Werid Error in a Link LIst?

Tags: java

I am facing a weird error while printing one of my Link List named "Number 1". This is the output that I get:

```
Operator
[+]
Number 1
[javax.swing.JFrame[frame0,301,232,550x400,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,
title=Calculator,resizable,normal,defaultCloseOperation=EXIT_ON_CLOSE,
rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,5,24,540x371,invalid,
layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,
flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],
rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]]
Number 2
[12]
Final Result
[24] " .
```

Please help in solving the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do a `.toString()` on a JFrame.

You might want to consider printing something more appropriate there to represent that JFrame.

What should Number 1 actually say? What would you like it to say?

Comment: Yeah I had extended a JDialog to print LinkList's... and had given this.Number1.toString....